# Does similarity between 2 partially ordered sets implies the same order?

Tags: order-theory

I'm confused at the definition of 2 similar partially ordered sets and I would like to ask for your help for a clarification please.

I use the book of Halmos (Naive set theory) in which the author gives the following definition:

> Two partially ordered sets (which may in particular be totally ordered and even well ordered) are called similar if there exists an order-preserving one-to-one correspondence between them.
>
> More explicitly: to say of the partially ordered sets $X$ and $Y$ that they are similar means that there exists a one-to-one correspondence, say $f$, from $X$ onto
> $Y$, such that if $a$ and $b$ are in $X$, then a necessary and sufficient condition
> that $f(a) \leq f(b)$ (in $Y$) is that $a \leq b$ (in $X$). A correspondence such as $f$ is sometimes called a similarity

What confuses me is that if we have $f(a) \leq f(b)$ then the relation $\leq$ (which is in fact a set of ordered pairs) contains the pair $(f(a),f(b))$ but there is no reason that $f(a) \in X$ and $f(b) \in X$. In other words, there is no reason that $\leq$ contains $(f(a),f(b))$ which causes a contradiction.

Am i wrong somewhere ? How should I understand the condition "$f(a) \leq f(b)$ (in $Y$) iff $a \leq b$ (in $X$)" in the definition ? Should I understand it as "if the ordered pair $(a,b)$ belongs to some set of ordered pairs, then the ordered pair $(f(a), f(b))$ also belongs to the same set" ? What intuition should I retain here ?

Thank you very much for your enlightment!

Comment: You're stumbling over a very common abuse of notation.  It would be technically correct to state $f(a) \leq_Y f(b) \iff a \leq_X b$.  But the subscripts are commonly omitted when they are clear from context.

Comment: The intuition for the condition is that is what Halmos means when he says that f is "order preserving". If a < b (in X) then when we apply the function f we know f(a) < f(b) (in Y). In some sense, X,Y have the same "structure" because we can map their elements in this special way. Since f is also a bijection, X,Y also have the same # of elements- so X,Y are quite similar in terms of structure and size. Hence, the term similarity, for f. Sometimes it's also called an isomorphism. iso is greek for "same", and morphism is greek for "shape"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more formal notation we could write, “Posets $P_1 = (X_1, \leq_1)$ and $P_2 = (X_2, \leq_2)$ are *similar* precisely when there exists a bijection $f$ from $X_1$ to $X_2$ such that for all $x,y \in X_1$, we have $x \leq_1 y$ if and only if $f(x) \leq_2 f(y)$. This clarifies that we are dealing with distinct order relations $\leq_1$ and $\leq_2$.

As Michael Carey wrote though, it is more common to describe such two posets $P_1$ and $P_2$ as *isomorphic*.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, if i am not wrong, what you mean is that $\leq_1$ and $\leq_2$ should be understood 2 different sets in the general case ?

Comment: Yes, one is a set of ordered pairs $(x_1, y_1)$ of elements of $X_1$, while the other contains pairs $(x_2, y_2)$ from $X_2$. For example, the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ ordered by $\subseteq$ [*is-a-subset-of*] is isomorphic to the set of ABO blood groups ordered by the *can-donate-to* relation. Thus can-donate-to is sort of, kind of “the same thing as” the $\subseteq$ relation of blood groups.

Comment: Oops! The set of ABO blood groups is isomorphic to $\{1,2\}$, not $\{1,2,3\}$. You do get isomorphism with $\{1,2,3\}$ if you augment ABO with the rhesus factor.